# Custom Tab Bar Background Image is not showing correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitabbar

I'm implementing a custom Tab bar for my iOS app. Im using the following code to display a background image:

```
 class TabNavigationMenu: UIView {
 // ...
 // ...
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
    UIImage(named: "tabBarbg.png")?.draw(in: self.bounds)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    if let image = image {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)
    }
 }
```

However, the tab bar is presented like this:

[image]

Also, when i make a view and present it anywhere else in the screen, it displays correctly. I'm using the same code there as well. Heres an example:

[image]

Any idea what the problem could be? I'm guessing the solution would also solve the faint blue line on top of the view...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to customize tab bar in ios

```
//Set the background color
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = .red
tabBar.backgroundImage =  UIImage(named: "tabBarbg.png")

//Set the item tint colors
tabBar.tintColor = .white
tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = .lightGray
```

Comment: That's not what i asked. I'm making a custom tab bar.

Comment: @SaadRehman how are you using your class TabNavigationMenu. Could you explain..?

Comment: I hade the original tabBar, then use this UIView to display my custom tab bar in its place. https://medium.com/sprinthub/creating-a-customized-tab-bar-in-ios-with-swift-41ed380f2a30 I'm using this link but I have to make a few changes to my custom Tab bar. I figured out what the problem was. I was using the frame of teh default tabBar to make the custom tab bar which gave it the default height of 49. Thats why the image kept repeating.